# can i create a function that includes multiple processes?

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
list1=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

as an example 
if the following lines are repeated many times in my code many times , how can i include them in one function and call that function when needed ?

```
i=0
while i<=len(list1)-1:
    if list1[i]==6:
        break
    i+=1
print(i)
x=i-3
if x<0:
    print('negative')
    x=0
if x>0:
    print('positive')
    print(x)
```

i tried just inserting them inside a function but it didnt work can you tell me why please ?
am still new to the world of python

Comment: Hello and welcome to both StackOverflow and Python!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us your attempt at inserting the code inside a function?

Comment: hi @DanielWalker its very long code to be honest and not similar to the one in the example above but when i try to run python it gives an error that some variables inside the function are not defined

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Without seeing what you've attempted, there's not a lot we can do to help you.

Comment: @DanielWalker ok ill try my best , give me some time pls :)